# Uniform integrability: it works correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and suppose that
$$\sup_n\int_{\Omega} h(u_n) dx<+\infty.$$

Can we conclude that for all $v\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$ the sequence $(v h(u_n))_n$ is uniformly integrable?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: no, it doesn't work. There is a theorem that says that a sequence of functions is uniformly integrability if and only if the integrals are uniform bounded and uniformly continuous

Comment: So I have to check the uniformly continuity of  the sequence $(h(u_n))_n$ too, isn't it?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: @Masacroso thank you for you help. If $h$ is a continuous function and $(u_n)_n$ a bounded sequence, do you think that it should be enough for the uniformly continuity of the sequence $(h(u_n))_n$?

Comment: continuity will not necessarily change the behavior of the $u_n$. The uniform continuity refer to this: we says that a collection of integrals are uniformly continuous if for any chosen $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta >0$ such that $$\mu(A)<\delta \implies \sup_ n \int_A |f_n| d\mu<\epsilon$$